# How do I factor $x^6+x^3+4$? Both real and complex

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I can't seem to figure out how to factor this: $x^6+x^3+4$

Supposed to give both the real and complex factors

Comment: **Hint:** Let $t=x^3$. Then $x^6+x^3+4=t^2+t+4$.

Comment: In general, $ax^{2n}+bx^n+c,\,a\neq0,\,n\in\mathbb N/\{0\}$ can be factored using the substitution $y\leadsto x^n$, then using the quadratic formula to find the roots, say $r_1$ and $r_2$ -- if any -- then the formula can be factored as $a(y-r_1)(y-r_2)$,  then re-substituting $x^n\leadsto y$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: set $u = x^{3}$ then you have $u^2+u+4 $

Then apply the quadratic Formula to factorize it....ones you have it go back to $x^3$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you factor it like $ax^2 + bx + c$ except that it will be in the form $(x^3+b)(x^3+d)$.

Comment: Then you can factor a bit more :-)

Comment: Indeed, if you can put it in that form then you can write it as a product of six linear factors (complex coefficients will be involved)